# pytest mock response with multiple calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to mock the response of api call but in my one function i have two seperate api call and i want to mock only one. below is the code and i want o mock only my second api call

```
apicall.py

def call_api():
    response_of_api1_to_get_token = request.post() # some url to post 1st. DO Not Mock this
    response_of_api2 = request.post() # some url to post 2nd api, i want to mock this
    
# test.py

import pytest
import requests_mock
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from apicall import call_api

def test_some_func():
    with requests_mock.mock() as m:
        m.get(requests_mock.ANY, status_code=500, text='some error')

        with pytest.raises(HTTPError):
            # You cannot make any assertion on the result
            # because some_func raises an exception and
            # wouldn't return anything
            call_api(a="a", b="b") # here it mock my first api
```

is there anyway i can avoid mocking 1st api call and do mock on 2nd api call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in `real_http=True` to the Mocker's init call. This will result in only mocking the requests that you have registered a URL for. In the example below, the request to test.com will be mocked, the one to google.com will not be mocked.

```py
import requests
import requests_mock
with requests_mock.Mocker(real_http=True) as m:
    m.get('http://test.com', text='resp')
    requests.get('http://test.com').text
    requests.get('https://www.google.com').text
```